# kable problem: 'longtable = T' and 'full_width = T' are required in my case but they seem to be incompatible

Tags: knitr, kable, kableextra, longtable

PROBLEM: How to knit/render in pdf a one column table, containing a continuous text and extending on a second page?
With the default "longtable = F", the table is truncated!
While specifying "longtable = T" the source doesn't compile!
The log signals:

> Dimension too large.
> \LT@max@sel #1#2->{\ifdim #2=\wd \tw@
> #1\else \number \c@LT@chunks \fi }{\th...
> l.167 \end{longtabu}

Below the text of the Rmd that compiles but truncates the table.
Removing `#` before `longtable`, it produces the error.

> .# (dots added to have the chunk limits visible)
> .---
> output: pdf_document
> .---
>
> .```{r}
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(kableExtra))
>
> tibble(Title = paste(paste(lorem:::ipsum(paragraphs = 20),
> collapse = " NEXT "), " *** END ***")) %>%
> kbl(booktabs = T,
> longtable = T
> ) %>%
> kable_styling(full_width = TRUE,
> latex_options = c("hold_position", "repeat_header"),
> repeat_header_continued =
> "\textit{(Continued on Next Page...)}"
> )
> .```
>
> END of TEST

Issue open also in [KableExtra GitHub repo](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/760#issue-1807439893)